# Chaining JavaScript promises in a loop - bluebird

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, bluebird

I have been reading up on promises using bluebird and have been trying to achieve the following:

I need to run func1 and func2 till the loop is over. Once that's done, I would like to run func3. The code is as follows:

**Note:** All the functions have a callback function (to show that the operation has completed successfully)

```
var jsObj = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]; // has 5 elements

for (var i = 0; i < jsObj.length; i++) {
var arr1 = [];
arr1 = jsObj[i];
func1(arr1).then(function(returnVal1) {
// finished func1
 func2(returnVal1).then(function(returnVal2) {
// finished func2
});
});
} // end of loop

// Now, I need to run the last function once the loop is complete
var data = ["1222"];
func3(data, function() {
alert("all done");
});
```

func1 and func2 are done using promises whereby the result is returned in the callback function variables returnVal1 and returnVal2. How can I chain/condense these three together so that one runs after the other in a loop and then runs func3 using just promises?

Cheers.

Comment: Are you trying to process the array sequentially (so you process the first item in the array and don't start processing the second until the first is done)?  Or are you OK with processing everything in parallel (running them all at once) as long as you know when everything is done?  Your question seems to indicate a bit of both and you've chosen an answer that runs the whole array in parallel and I wasn't sure that's what you're actually asking for.

Comment: Well actually parallel would be ok and it doesn't affect me in my current question but is there a way to do this sequentially i.e. starting from index 0 till index 4 (in my case)?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do it sequentially.  This question needs to be one or the other so people can answer it one way.  You've already accepted an answer that does things in parallel.  If parallel is OK logically and it doesn't overwhelm the target server (or trigger rate limiting), then parallel is better because it's usually faster to complete everything.

Comment: True, its because I am maintaining the index as well and I can just use that index to sort it out myself instead of performing a sequential operation. However, just for my knowledge, would you be able to post the sequential way of doing it as one of the answers please? I'm new to promises and I am learning everything that is coming my way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map the data to promises, then use promise.all:

```
var jsObj = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]; // has 5 elements

var promises = jsObj.map(function(obj){
 return func1(obj).then(function(value){
   return func2(value).then(function(val){
     return val;
   });
 });
});

Promise.all(promises).then(function(results){
 alert("all done");
});
```

You may also chain the promises e.g.:

```
.then(a=>b(a)).then(b=>c)
```

instead of

```
.then(a=>b(a).then(b=>c))
```

Comment: Can't use ES6 sorry. Need to support IE11 too.

Comment: @TheNewbie Babel?

Comment: @the newbie edited,  however im not shure if bluebird polyfills Promise.all ( yep it does...)

Comment: In the alert("all done"), I can run my third function right because I didn't see func3() here.

Comment: How would this : .then(a=>b(a)).then(b=>c) .. work in my scenario? will it finish the loop and then go onto c?

Comment: Plus, what does "results" get once all the promises are complete? The return value from func2 or both func1 and func2?

Comment: @the newbie an array from all the values of func2.

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsObj = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]; // has 5 elements

for (var i = 0; i < jsObj.length; i++) {

   func1(jsObj[i]).then(function(returnVal1) {
        // finished func1
       func2(returnVal1).then(function(returnVal2) {
         // finished func2
          finalFn();
       });
    });
} // end of loop

// Now, I need to run the last function once the loop is complete
var count = 0;
function finalFn(){
  count++;
  if(count == jsObj.length){
     var data = ["1222"];
     func3(data, function() {
       alert("all done");
     });
  }
}
```